Custom upload functionality issue in WooCommerce registration form
I am trying to allow the user to upload an item on WooCommerce registration using the following:
function custom_save_register_form($customer_id) {
    if (isset($_POST['postcode'])) {
        update_user_meta($customer_id, 'postcode', sanitize_text_field($_POST['postcode']));
    }
    if (isset($_POST['huisnummer'])) {
        update_user_meta($customer_id, 'huisnummer', sanitize_text_field($_POST['huisnummer']));
    }

    // ID Kaart uploaden
    if (!empty($_FILES['id_card']['name'])) {
        $uploaded_file = $_FILES['id_card'];
        
        // Get plugin folder
        $plugin_dir = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__);
        $upload_dir = $plugin_dir . 'id-cards/'; // Specific folder in the plugin directory

        // Create the folder if it does not exist
        if (!file_exists($upload_dir)) {
            if (!wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir)) {
                error_log('Error creating the folder: ' . $upload_dir);
                return; // Stop if the folder cannot be created
            }
        }

        // Move file
        $upload_path = $upload_dir . basename($uploaded_file['name']);
        if (move_uploaded_file($uploaded_file['tmp_name'], $upload_path)) {
            // Save the URL of the file as user metadata
            $upload_url = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'id-cards/' . basename($uploaded_file['name']);
            update_user_meta($customer_id, 'id_card', $upload_url);
        } else {
            error_log('Error moving the file: ' . $upload_path);
        }
    }
}

But the upload is not saved on the server.

I think that file upload is not allowed via POST method here (so $_FILES is always empty)… The alternative should be to do that via Javascript / Ajax. Also, you should not upload files to your plugin, but in the wp-content/uploads folder within a dedicated subdirectory, renaming uploaded files to get a unique filename.

please update including error message if not visible please debug implementing try and catch methods.
